# Complex analytic function on a line

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

a) Let $D$ be a domain whose boundary $C$ contains a straight-line segment $L$.  Let $f(z)$ be analytic in $D$ and continous on $L$.  Assume also that $\Im(f) = v(x,y)$ vanishes on $L$.  Prove that $f$ is analytic on $L$.

I am a bit confused with what it means to be analytic on a line.  I know how to show analyticity in a domain, via Morera, but for a line, I am not so sure.

b) Show that there is no function $f(z)$ analytic for $y>0$ and continuous for $y\geq0$ such that
$$
f(z) = |x|
$$

Thanks

Comment: For a general subset $A$ of the plane, we say that a function is analytic on $A$ if it is analytic on some open set containing $A$. Should that be $f(z)=|z|$ in part (b)?

Comment: The phrasing of the b part seems off. Perhaps the intention is to show there is no such function with $f(x)=|x|$ for real $x$?

Comment: Phrasing is correct.  We have that $x$ is the real part of z

Comment: If the phrasing is correct, it is *definitely* off. Saying there is no function with some properties such that … and following it with an explicit definition of the function, is just a very convoluted way of saying that the given function does not have the stated properties.

Comment: Hi Eager Student, just wanted to let you know that you can [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to all of your questions to signal to the person who answered that you are satisfied with their answer (among other reasons).  Hope to see you around more!

Answer (score 2):

Hint for part a: The [Schwarz reflection principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle), combined with a bit of rotation and translation.

Hint for part b, assuming the requirement is $f(x)=|x|$ for real $x$: Find a function that satisfies this around the positive real axis. Repeat with the negative axis. Can you reconcile the two?

**Addition** to part b: By reflection, you get an entire function $g$ so that $g(x)=|x|$ when $x$ is real. In particular $g(x)=x$ for $x>0$, hence by the principle of analytic continuation (the uniqueness part thereof) $g(z)=z$ for all $z$. But that clearly contradicts $g(x)=-x$ when $x<0$.

… okay, so that was overkill: Clearly, analyticity fails at the origin, and you don't need to invoke analytic continuation. But the argument as I gave it will work even if the origin is excluded from consideration.

Comment: I see how after we translate and rotate to the real axis and use the reflection principle with the analytic continuation
$$
g(w) = \left\{\begin{array}[lr] f(w) & Im(w)\geq 0 \\
\bar{f}(\bar{w}) & Im(w)\leq 0
\end{array}\right.
$$
Thanks.
For part b is it the same sort of thing.  We have that $f$ is real on the real axis and analytic in the upper half plane so for $g$ defined above $g$ is entire and $f$ is constant, so it does not satisfy the condition.

Comment: I think you need more for part b. I expanded my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For part (b), I think it is a simple consequence of $C-R$ equations that a real valued analytic function defined in a domain $D$, is constant.